# Find all $(x,y,z)$ such that $dF(x,y,z)$ is invertible

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, inverse

Here $F:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ is given by $F(x,y,z)=(e^{x}\cos(y),e^{x}\sin(y),z^3)$.

The question is to find all $(x,y,z)$ such that $dF(x,y,z)$ is invertible.

I think it is a question about the inverse function theorem(because it comes from the part of exercise on the inverse function theorem). But I cannot find out how to use it.

I think from linear algebra, what I need to do is just finding out all the points that the matrix of $dF$ is invertible, may I please ask if it is correct?

If it is incorrect, could someone please tell me why? May I please ask how can I find all $(x,y,z)$ such that $dF(x,y,z)$ is invertible? Thanks so much!

Comment: Nope, you're correct. Find the matrix $\mathrm{d}F(x, y, z)$, and use the fact that a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is $0$.

Comment: @MichaelLee is not $ 0$

Comment: Whoops, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jacobian of $F$ computes to
$$[dF(x,y,z)]=\left[\matrix{e^x\cos y&-e^x\sin y&0\cr
e^x\sin y&e^x\cos y&0\cr
0&0&3z^2\cr}\right]$$
and has
$${\rm det}\big(dF(x,y,z)\bigr)=3e^{2x}z^2\ .$$
It follows that $dF(x,y,z)$ is invertible at all points $(x,y,z)\in{\mathbb R}^3$ with $z\ne0$.